How to debug compilation stage in C++ to check template specifications and type checkings
I am writing a file parser. To avoid multiple implementations of one function, I wrote the following codes. Here is a minimal example: https://cppinsights.io/s/d7b81581
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

class VertexTexture {
private:
  float m_u, m_v;

public:
  // helper functions ...
  inline void set_u(float u) { m_u = u; }
  inline void set_v(float v) { m_v = v; }
};

class ObjParser {
private:
  std::vector<VertexTexture> m_textures; // store all VertexTextures
  std::string m_line;                    // current line in file
  // ...
public:
  template <typename Container>
  void parseUVfloats(const std::string &line,
                     std::back_insert_iterator<Container> elem_iter);
  // parse VertexTexture from `m_line` and push the result into `m_textures`
  // You can check implementation below
  void parseVertexTexture() {
    parseUVfloats(m_line, std::back_inserter(m_textures));
    // ...
  }
};

// <=== check if `T` has `m_u` and `m_v` in `float` type
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasUVFloatMembers : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct HasUVFloatMembers<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::m_u), decltype(&T::m_v)>>
    : std::integral_constant<
          bool, std::is_floating_point<decltype(T::m_u)>::value &&
                    std::is_floating_point<decltype(T::m_v)>::value> {};
// ===>

template <typename Container>
void ObjParser::parseUVfloats(const std::string &line,
                              std::back_insert_iterator<Container> elem_iter) {
  // static assertion, if I comment this, everything works fine
  static_assert(HasUVFloatMembers<typename Container::value_type>::value,
                "Container must have m_u, m_v members in float type.");

  std::vector<std::string> split_result = {
      "f", "1.0", "2.0"}; // split the line and get the result

  typename Container::value_type elem;
  try {
    elem.set_u(std::stof(split_result.at(1)));
    elem.set_v(std::stof(split_result.at(2)));
  } catch (const std::out_of_range &e) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  *elem_iter = elem;
}

int main() {}

And here is the error during compilation:
/home/insights/insights.cpp:48:17: error: static assertion failed due to requirement 'HasUVFloatMembers<VertexTexture, void>::value': Container must have m_u, m_v members in float type.
   48 |   static_assert(HasUVFloatMembers<typename Container::value_type>::value,
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/insights/insights.cpp:28:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'ObjParser::parseUVfloats<std::vector<VertexTexture>>' requested here
   28 |     parseUVfloats(m_line, std::back_inserter(m_textures));
      |     ^
1 error generated.
Error while processing /home/insights/insights.cpp.

Which is really confusing me. I have other template functions for parsing, if I comment the static assertions, everything works fine, even the result is correct.
I know that SO can't ask two questions at once. Besides, there are other template functions have the same problem. So, my problem is that, is there a way to check what happened during template specifications and static assertions during the compilation stage?

Update
If you make m_u and m_v public in c++17, the compilation will succeed.

Please post a [mre] that we can copy-paste as is to our editor and reproduce the problem.

@wohlstad Wait a minute. I thought this is minimal enough. I will make a runnable code

Note that you code is missing some #includes. Also what is Mtl ? And pair<Mtl::MtlName, ...> indicates that you have using namespace std; which is not recommended anyway (see: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?).

@wohlstad My bad. I will update my code soon. By the way, I know not to use using namespace std;, I used using std::pair, ;)

Thanks. BTW - MSVC still requires #include <iterator>. Anyway I will have a look and answer if I'll figure it out.

@wohlstad Thanks a lot, I will remember to include that in my code.

Try to change struct HasUVFloatMembers<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::m_u), decltype(&T::m_v)>> to struct HasUVFloatMembers<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::m_u), decltype(T::m_v)>> (i.e. remove the &s). Why did you actually add the &s ?

@wohlstad I tried, there is no use, and supposed to have no use. Adding &  or not is just to get the pointer or the float itself. Both ways make sense once there are m_v and m_v in the object. I guess the problem is not here.

Strangly I no longer get the assert in MSVC 2022 (c++20) after removing the &. Making the members m_u, m_v public instead also does the trick. I am not sure why.

@wohlstad I tried to just make m_u and m_v to public in c++17, which made sense. Really strange. I will update my question

"If you make m_u and m_v public in c++17, the compilation will succeed...." See Is it ill-formed to attempt to access private member of a class to sfinae out overload? and Can SFINAE detect private access violations?. Also Private member access in template substitution and SFINAE

@LiuYuan I wouldn't call it strange;  I was just about to tell you that the private is your problem, but then you updated it already. Why would it be strange? "Substitution failure is not an error". The members are private, so your checker can't access them, but... it's not an error, so it just fails. Sometimes, things that we might wish were errors still aren't :-) And decltype doesn't get any special treatment -- you can't use it to bypass access control, even if you only want to know what it is, not actually use it.

@ChristianStieber Thank you for your patient answer! So I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to do the same thing? Or I can only just wait the program to abort during the runtime?

I know nothing about your actual project, or why it would abort at runtime. Most of the time, the reason one would check for certain properties of a type is because one wants to use these properties of the type, so it should still fail compilation if the type doesn't have them. Since your template can't use these private members anyway, you might even want to check for something else, something that you actually do use. Or you can just call it a day and deal with the more obscure compiler errors you'll get when you don't get the nice static_assert message -- it's not a concept anyway.
